# Limite de hojas en mPDF de PHP

Tags: php, mpdf

Buen día. Estoy utilizando la librería mPDF para PHP, misma que estoy teniendo problemas al desplegar más de 33 hojas, si la infomación crece al punto de llegar las 34 ó más hojas, no muestra información ni errores.
Ya intenté cambiando los timeout de PHP, activando el modo debug de la librería y no funciona.
¿Existe un limite de hojas por archivo en la librería? ¿Alguna sugerencia?
Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Según la [documentación](https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/known-issues.html) (en inglés):

#### Páginas en blanco o algunas secciones faltantes

Si transfiere una gran cantidad de código, mediante `WriteHTML()` ya sea como estilos CSS o como código HTML, puede obtener como resultado una página en blanco.

La función de PHP `preg_replace()` tiene una longitud máxima de cadena que analizará, por defecto, alrededor de **100,000** caracteres. Sobre esto, si se sobrepasa, PHP silenciosamente devolverá un valor nulo. *¡Por lo tanto, las cadenas largas de código serán reemplazadas por nada!*

Puede aumentar el valor de [pcre.backtrack_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/es/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit) en tiempo de ejecución si su sistema lo permite. `pcre.backtrack_limit` es configurable desde PHP> = 5.2.0

**Como solución:** Divida su HTML en fragmentos y páselos de a uno por vez a `WriteHTML()`.

#### El programa muere sin mostrar un mensaje de error al generar un gran archivo PDF

Existe un tiempo de espera debido a la configuración de Apache `TimeOut` hará que la secuencia de comandos finalice sin mostrar un mensaje de error.

**Como solución:** Aumentar el límite de tiempo de PHP.